# GitLab - analyze command failing

Tags: flutter, dart, gitlab, continuous-integration

I want to run `dart analyze` and `flutter analyze` commands as part of my ci process (gitlab) using this `gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```yaml
before_script:
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
  - sh -c 'wget -qO- https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -'
  - sh -c 'wget -qO- https://storage.googleapis.com/download.dartlang.org/linux/debian/dart_stable.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dart_stable.list'
  - apt-get update -qy
  - apt-get install -y dart
  - apt-get install -y xz-utils
  

  # Install Flutter
  - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable --depth 1
  - export PATH="$PATH:`pwd`/flutter/bin"

dart_analyze:
  stage: analyze
  script:
    - flutter pub get
    - dart analyze

flutter_analyze:
  stage: analyze
  script:
    - flutter pub get
    - flutter analyze
```

As you can see `dart analyze` command starts to run (screenshot taken from the pipeline while running)

[image]

After that, I will get this error:

```yaml
error - flutter/packages/flutter_driver/test/src/real_tests/wait_test.dart:105:3 - The function 'group' isn't defined. Try importing the library that defines 'group', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'group'. - undefined_function

error - flutter/packages/flutter_driver/test/src/real_tests/wait_test.dart:106:5 - The function 'test' isn't defined. Try importing the library that defines 'test', correcting the name to the name of an existing function, or defining a function named 'test'. - undefined_function

    **More errors in here, and the end of the errors will display those lines:**

   info - flutter/packages/integration_test/example/test_driver/failure_test.dart:7:8 - The imported package 'test' isn't a dependency of the importing package. Try adding a dependency for 'test' in the 'pubspec.yaml' file. - depend_on_referenced_packages
   info - flutter/packages/integration_test/test/binding_test.dart:153:23 - Unreachable member 'getVMTimeline' in an executable library. Try referencing the member or removing it. - unreachable_from_main
   info - flutter/packages/integration_test/test/binding_test.dart:159:24 - Unreachable member 'getVMTimelineMicros' in an executable library. Try referencing the member or removing it. - unreachable_from_main
   info - flutter/packages/integration_test/test/binding_test.dart:165:22 - Unreachable member 'setVMTimelineFlags' in an executable library. Try referencing the member or removing it. - unreachable_from_main
   info - flutter/packages/integration_test/test/binding_test.dart:170:22 - Unreachable member 'clearVMTimeline' in an executable library. Try referencing the member or removing it. - unreachable_from_main
11439 issues found.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Here you can find the full log [from the pipeline](https://gitlab.com/Tamir198/hash_that/-/jobs/5170114493)

---

I checked locally that everything is okay when running `dart analyze` and `flutter analyze`:

[image]

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Start the docker image you use on your computer, launch the same command and you will be able to debug.
Tips create an image with all you before script to save time on ci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the correct syntax :

```yaml
code_quality:
  stage: test
  image: ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter:stable

  before_script:
    - flutter pub get

  script:
    - flutter analyze
    - flutter test
```